# no output from qtree

Tags: qtree

My first experiment with qtree puzzled me: why is the first tree output (it is copied from the manual) and the second not?

```
\documentclass[msmallroyalvopaper
    ]{memoir}

\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}

text - this works:

\Tree [.DP my pony ]

but this produces nothing:

\Tree [.Human Person Stuff] 

end
\end{document}
```

Comment: add empty space before closing bracket

Comment: works! thank you - it would be great if the manual would indicate this! -  zarko would you state this as an answer which I accept?

Answer (score 1):

`qtree` syntax require empty space before closing brackets:

```
\documentclass[msmallroyalvopaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}
text - this works:

\Tree [.DP my pony ] % here you have

but this produces nothing (if you not add space before `]`:

\Tree [.Human Person Stuff ] % here i added

end
\end{document}
```

[image]